# Mulesoft Anypoint Studio DevKit - @Connector vs @Module ( No need for config-ref )

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am trying to create a component that does not need a connection to another source or for that fact a connection strategy... but no matter what I try I cannot prevent the component from having a "Basic Settings" > "Connector Configuration" dropdown/create/edit section in the "Mule Properties" section when working with the components settings.

Does anyone know how I create an Anypoint DevKit Component that does not need a "Connector Configuration" ?

My understanding is that annotations play a big role in defining this and that the connecotr uses the @Connector and that someone has mentioned to me the need to substitute this with the @Module annotation as this indicates no need for a connection... but even when doing this the config options remain on the component.

Please see the following code:
( note : I am trying to create a custom logger and need only to have several inputs and a dropdown operation which I can already get working. )

```
package au.com.company.companylogger;

import org.mule.api.annotations.Configurable;
import org.mule.api.annotations.Module;
import org.mule.api.annotations.Processor;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Default;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Optional;



@Module(name="company-logger", friendlyName="companyLogger", schemaVersion="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
public class companyLoggerConnector {




    @Processor(name="company-logger-trace", friendlyName="TRACE")
    public String companyLoggerTrace(String strStep) {
        /*
         * MESSAGE PROCESSOR CODE GOES HERE
         */
        return "TRACE : " + strStep;
    }




    @Processor(name="company-logger-debug", friendlyName="DEBUG")
    public String companyLoggerDebug(String strStep) {
        /*
         * MESSAGE PROCESSOR CODE GOES HERE
         */
        return "DEBUG : " + strStep;
    }
}
```

I unfortunately do not have enough reputation to provide you with an image of the config I do not need.

Any help or suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Anypoint Devkit 3.6, the "config-ref" attribute on elements became required, so you NEED to create a global element definition for your connector. As far as I know, there isn't a way to get around this at this point.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is both fortunate and unfortunate to be informed of this fact... I wont be wasting any more time on trying to disable what appears to be enforced... but also good to know because I can now try to work around or with this enforced path... Do you have any links to online information that verify this?

Comment: I just received confirmation from Mulesoft that this is the case and that its currently under consideration with out confirmation to handle / remove the restriction

Comment: since Devkit 3.8.X this will be no longer required, and you will have @Connectors without config-ref

Answer (score 0):

The config element name can be changed using the configElementName attribute in @Connector or @Module

```
@Module(name="company-logger", friendlyName="companyLogger", configElementName="xx", schemaVersion="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

If you do not set this attribute, it will default to "config". May be if you provide an empty string or null then it will not show up. I haven't tried it before though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. I tried adding it with "xx" and "" and also null but null was not compiling due to syntax issues. But still thank you for the suggestion, it looked promising :)